# Variable links problem in TwinCAT 3 on windows 10

Tags: twincat

I am using TwinCAT 3 on Windows 10, and create a PLC project in visual studio 2013 shell(isolated). When I try to link an output variable to an input variable by “Change Link”, there is always no avaible variable to be linked.

The pop-up window is as following:
[Attach Variable pop-up window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5OHC.png)

What may be the problem?

Comment: Have you built your project? Are you sure you are using AT %I* etc? If both are yes, check the datatypes the Filippos answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to link the variable with a project instance variable you need to uncheck "exclude same image" otherwise if you want to link the variable with a hardware IO you need to have an IO tree attached to your Ethercat Master.

Comment: And of course you map a Software Input to a Hardware Input and a Software Output to a Hardware Output

Comment: How do you attach an io  to your master ?